# mySQL Permission Errors

Tags: mysql

When I attempt to create a database this happens:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE testing;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'testing'
```

When I run select user(); this happens:

```
mysql> select user();
+-------------+
| user()      |
+-------------+
| X@localhost |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I attempt to login as root this happens:

```
> mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried over 15 different GRANT and FLUSH PRIVILEGES methods. Including putting the commands in a text file and doing it that way. I am on Mountain Lion using mySQL Server and Sequal Pro for managing the database.

Sequal Pro tells me that I cannot add a database as well. I have attempted to completely reinstall mySQL and that didn't seem to work either. I am new to mySQL and just need to start creating a database, I am going through the Django Book tutorials before I start on a project.

The only way I am able to access mysql is if i use

```
mysql -u X -p
```

However, that leads back to my permission errors up top.

Comment: The default username is `mysql` and either no password or `mysql` as password.

Comment: When logging into MySQL, you don't put a space between `-p` and the password. `mysql -u root -pMypassword`

Comment: @Aiias That was a formatting mistake by OP.

Comment: If I attempt to create a database after just running mysql, i get the same permission error

Comment: Please run this query : `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_CUSER();`

Comment: mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+-------------+----------------+
| USER()      | CURRENT_USER() |
+-------------+----------------+
| X@localhost | @localhost     |
+-------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Comment: mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+-------------+----------------+
| USER()      | CURRENT_USER() |
+-------------+----------------+
| X@localhost | @localhost     |
+-------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>